# Anonymous function error and what is anonymous function?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i have one view called visitors view in my project. In that view it contain two drop downs **CustomerName** and **ContactPerson** if i select the CustomerName the CustomerName related ContactPerson name will be automatically load in contact person drop down.its like Cascading DropDown. This process is working fine in normal mode that is when i run my application this cascading dropdown is working fine. But when i publish my project in LocalHost and run the application both the dropdown are not loading the values from db. These cascading is not working. so i inspect the issue in browser at that time i got these issue. The issue are below. please  any one tell me what are the issue is this? Give  me solution for this problem

[image]

**My ViewModel**

```
   public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerID { get; set; }
   public string CustomerName { get; set; }
   public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerContactID { get; set; }
   public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
```

**My Controller**

```
     public ActionResult Create()
    {
      return View();
    }
     public JsonResult GetCustomers()
    {
        return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetContactPersobByCustomerId(string customerId)
    {
        Guid Id = Guid.Parse(customerId);
        var customercontacts = from a in db.CustomerContacts where   a.CustomerID == Id select a;

        return Json(customercontacts);
    }
```

**My View**

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

          <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
         @Html.Label("Contact Person", new { @class = "control-label" })
         @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "CustomerContactID" })
         </div>
         </div>
```

**My Jquery**

```
<script>
 $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/VisitorsForm/GetCustomers",
        datatype: "Json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#CustomerID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');
            });
        }
    });

    $('#CustomerID').change(function () {

        $('#CustomerContactID').empty();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/VisitorsForm/GetContactPersobByCustomerId",
            datatype: "Json",
            data: { CustomerID: $('#CustomerID').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#CustomerContactID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerContactID + '">' + value.ContactReference + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The error 404 not found.. Nothing to do with the anonymous function. I think the URL which you are trying to hit is not right. yes I agree it works in your dev but not after you published. Click on the link after `GET` in the above error and you will be able to see the actual error

Comment: You need to post your code, not images of it!

Comment: ok i will post my code wait

Comment: The issue is when you hit the GetCustomers Url. Type this directly in the URL and let us know what you see. `http://192.168.0.36:8066/VisitorsForm/GetCustomers`

Comment: Most likely answer to your problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls.

Comment: ok reddy wait i will run and see

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I feel its the same too.

Comment: [Error][2]
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rWP1e.jpg this only i got when i used that url

Comment: Finally any one tell me solution for this problem

Comment: Stephen i post my code there is any mistake in my code

Comment: You code and output looks ok, No problem there. I am very much sure It is some URL issues. But at the moment not able to guess what else might cause it

Comment: yes in normal its perfectly working but in local host only it creating issue

Comment: @Sruthi if you have the script tag in your cshtml page itself then do this. Replace `/VisitorsForm/GetCustomers'`  with  '@Url.Action("GetCustomers","VisitorsForm")' also the same with your another ajax with `GetContactPersobByCustomerId`

Answer (score -2):

Your anonymous function should look like this:

```
(function($){
    $.ajax({
        //etc
    })
})(jQuery)
```

The way you have it $ is not in scope inside the anonymous function. It has to be passed in as a function parameter.

Comment: Can you please explain how this random code style recommendation relates to the question?

Comment: The question was regarding the error circled in the image. The code posted (in the image) which is related to the line `$(function(){`. I was attempting to show the correct syntax which should be `(function($){...` which fixes the error.

Comment: @JimG `$(function(){` is correct. it is a short hand to document ready style. And the code you posted is a Closure syntax which is not related to this question

Comment: @Reddy OK, thanks. I guess my thinking was off. I appreciate the feedback.